# WPF binding TextBox to integer property without throwing exception

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am binding TextBox.Text to `int` property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Lines, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

private int _lines = 10;
public int Lines
{
    get { return _lines; }
    set { _lines = value; }
}
```

everything *works as expected* with this simple code, there is even validation for the TextBox. There is however exception `System.FormatException` thrown in the Output log. My question is: 
Is there elegant way to get rid of the exception without reimplementing almost **everything** myself? 
By everything I mean validators, convertors, etc. simply ton of code that does not do anything but call `Int32.TryParse` instead of `Int32.Parse`. Not that exception thrown and handled by wpf would be a big problem, but full log makes finding actual problems much more difficult.

Comment: you could prevent the user from inputting invalid values

Comment: @Domysee you mean something like handling textChanged and rollback the field if it cannot be parsed? I guess that could work - not exactly same behaviour but it could.

Comment: exactly, I would handle the PreviewKeyDown event and cancel if its an invalid key, but in principle its the same

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't all that clear, but I assume you are referring to an exception that occurs if the user enters invalid text (i.e. non-numeric, non-integer data).

AFAIK, WPF does not include a built-in control that restricts user input. So your options are:

- Use one of [the several third-party implementations of a WPF masked text-box control](http://www.bing.com/search?q=wpf%20masked%20textbox).
- Host the `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox` control in your WPF program, i.e. using [WindowsFormsHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost(v=vs.110).aspx).
- Use custom validation in a regular `TextBox` control to process the input and avoid having WPF make a failed attempt to parse the invalid text.
- Live with the exception.

Comment: Well.. the point of my question is - if there is default conversion including validation for integers why does it throw exceptions. And the answer I am after if there is a workaround for this exception without a lot of effort - answer that there is none is also valid answer(for now I can live with it, but it puzzled me nonetheless)

Comment: @wondra: _"if there is default conversion including validation"_ -- is there? It depends on what you mean by "validation"; to me, that means user feedback and disabling of related controls (e.g. "OK" button). What do _you_ mean? Why should your definition preclude the possibility of thrown exceptions, given that catching and handling a thrown exception is a valid technique for implementing validation?

Comment: @wondra: _"if there is a workaround for this exception without a lot of effort"_ -- again, is there? It depends on what you mean by "workaround" and "a lot of effort". For example, I personally consider the `System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox` work-around I mentioned in my answer to be _not_ "a lot of effort". Without _precisely_ defining your terms and conditions, it's impossible to know what answer would address those terms and conditions.